# Initial value problems with y values

Tags: calculus, integration, initial-value-problems

So I'm having trouble understanding how to do initial value problems using y values with respect to x. For instance,

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 3x^{2}y^2$ where $y(1) = 1$

I know you can divide both sides by $y^2$ and then integrating on the RHS will give $x^3 + c$ but how does the LHS operate?

Also, in a situation where $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2 - 5y$ where $y(0) = 1$ you can rearrange it to get $\frac{dy}{dx} + 5y = 2$ But then there is apparently an integrating factor of $e^{5x}$ Where does that come from? What steps am I missing?

Comment: Write $\frac{dy}{y^2} = 3x^2 dx$ and integrate both sides. For the second, trying Googling "integrating factor".

Comment: I understand the concept of applying the integrand to $e$,  but the $y$ must stay behind in order for $5$ to become $5x$

Comment: Indeed, the method of integrating factors applies to ODEs of the form $y' + P(x) y = Q(x)$, producing the integrating factor $e^{\int P(x)dx}$. Hence the $y$ is "left behind".